# Java return method from inside anonymous inner class

Tags: java, methods, anonymous-class

I have a method called `play()`. Inside of the class, I have a `Timer` (`java.util.Timer`), and an anonymous inner class of type `TimerTask`. Here is my code:

```
public static void play() {
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            ...
        }, 0, 100); // Run every 10 milliseconds starting in 0 milliseconds (immediately)
}
```

Now the question is... I wish to return from the method `play` from inside the anonymous inner class (within the `...`), but if I call "`return`", it will return from the "`run`" method inside the inner class. How do I return from the `play` method inside of the anonymous inner class?

*[The title isn't very clear; I couldn't phrase it well. Please edit the title if you can think of a better title.]*

Comment: That's not possible at all. The `run()` method is run in another thread; the call to the `play()` method might be already finished by the time the `run()` method is called for the first time.

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: He want to break `play()` method execution inside  `TimerTask` anonymous inner class object `run()` method.

Comment: Are trying to WAIT for the run method to finish inside the play method?

Comment: Never Mind. See the answer below (accepted answer). The `run()` method actually ends once the timer is set, since the timer is run on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function `play` should return immediatly, since the timer operates on another thread, thus there is no need to return outside the inner class.

Comment: Good Point. I forgot about that.